# safari can't reload off-line saved reading list items

Tags: safari, mojave, reading-list

I am on safari 12.0.1 and macOS 10.14.1.

Safari simply cannot reload whatever I saved *offline* in the reading list -- the console get full of the same error message

Thanks for the support.

[image]

Comment: If you have virus protection installed (Norton, Sophos, etc) disable or uninstall, and retest. Report back with your findings.

Comment: Thanks @IconDaemon – I had indeed already deactivated (and even removed from the extensions) https://redmorph.com  which gives sometimes issues ...but it doesn't seem to work yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem. I think it's all about permissions and privacy.
I did this and it's helped:

1. Pull down the  Apple menu and choose ‘System Preferences’
2. Choose “Security & Privacy” control panel
3. Now select the “Privacy” tab, then from the left-side menu select “Full Disk Access”
4. Click the lock icon in the lower left corner of the preference panel and authenticate with an admin level login
5. Now click the [+] plus button to add an application with full disk access
6. Navigate to the /Applications and choose “Safari” to grant it Full Disk Access privileges
7. Relaunch Safari and try to open saved pages in offline mode

Comment: thanks -- it seems to be working (they might have a bug though: the shortcut opening the reading list, ctrl+cmd+2, does not work for me anymore...but that's another issue)